# DialogFlow CX forgets events in detectIntent response

Tags: frontend, event-handling, dialogflow-cx

I'm using dialogFlow cx from my frontend application with detectIntent request.
In every Page I have added two events.

1. sys.no-match-1 that re-prompts user
2. sys.no-match-2 that allows user in case of next no-match to make transition to next specified page instead of re-prompting.
   But the behavior is that, the dialogFlow forgets after triggering no-match-1 and next time instead of triggering no-match-2 it again and again triggering no-match-1.

[image]

Is there any way to allow dialogFlow to remember the last event and start from next one in the next detectIntent request?

Comment: Does this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454343/issues-with-state-pages) help you?

Comment: No, Not really!

Comment: Hi @AhmadCoachendo,I posted a workaround in my answer I hope it will help you.If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

Normally `sys.no-match-2` will trigger when user input does not match any of the  training phrases after `sys.no.match-1` triggered. Without looking into your project it is very difficult to answer why `sys.no-match-2` is not triggering.So I recommend you raise a ticket with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support). If not, create a thread in Google’s Issue Tracker using this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659). You can also STAR the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

These are some basic steps you can follow to solve your issue:

1. Make sure that the [Classification Threshold](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#settings-ml) is not very low.
2. If possible, train your agent again using Advanced NLU.
3. Make sure that there is no overlapping between intents.

As a workaround  you can try using `parameter`($session.counters.noMatchCnt = 2) and `no-match-default` for your requirement.

[image]

Here the `sys.no-match-default` event will trigger when user input does not match any of the training phrases. When the `sys.no-match-default` event is triggered again, it will satisfy the condition `$session.counters.noMatchCnt = 2` and then it will route to the page you have given

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, Dialogflow CX will trigger the next no-match event if, in the next turn conversation (same session), the agent doesn't detect any routes. Please make sure the no-match-1 transition is not filled.

[image: Event Handler Transition]